# KnpGaufette/Symfony2/AmazonS3

Tags: php, curl, symfony, configuration, amazon-s3

I am trying to combine Symfony2, KnpGaufetteBundle & Amazon S3.
From the KnpGaufette Bundle i got an xml definition to use for my config. But it's in xml and my config is in yml. And somehow i can't get my head around it. How do i define the following variables in yml? And what do they mean?

```
<service id="acme.s3" class="AmazonS3">
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="key">%acme.aws_key%</argument>
        <argument key="secret">%acme.aws_secret_key%</argument>
    </argument>
</service>

<service id="acme.s3.adapter" class="Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3">
    <argument type="service" id="acme.s3"></argument>
    <argument>%acme.s3.bucket_name%</argument>
</service>

<service id="acme.fs" class="Gaufrette\Filesystem">
    <argument type="service" id="acme.s3.adapter"></argument>
</service>
```

---

### Update with full Solution

So, to actually get it working, not only do we have to put down the config in yml (which has been solved by chmeliuk -> thanks), but we also need to configure the cacert.pem file for curl.
You can get a proper one here: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Now put this wherever you want and then use the following lines with the additional **certificate_authority** entry:

```
services:
    acme.s3:
        class: AmazonS3
        arguments:
            options: { key: %acme.aws_key%, secret: %acme.aws_secret_key%, certificate_authority: "pathWhereYouDidPutThisFile/cacert.pem" }

    acme.s3.adapter:
        class: Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3
        arguments: 
            service: @acme.s3
            bucket_name: %acme.s3.bucket_name%

    acme.fs:
        class: Gaufrette\Filesystem
        arguments: 
            adapter: @acme.s3.adapter
```

This solves the CA Cert cURL Error 60 which you might have otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

same configuration but in yml format.

```
services:
    acme.s3:
        class: AmazonS3
        arguments:
            options: { key: %acme.aws_key%, secret: %acme.aws_secret_key% }

    acme.s3.adapter:
        class: Gaufrette\Adapter\AmazonS3
        arguments: 
            service: @acme.s3
            bucket_name: %acme.s3.bucket_name%

    acme.fs:
        class: Gaufrette\Filesystem
        arguments: 
            adapter: @acme.s3.adapter
```

to define such parameters as: %acme.aws_key%, %acme.aws_secret_key%, %acme.s3.bucket_name%  add to your project parameters.yml file (or to same config where you define services) next lines:

```
parameters:
    acme.aws_key: YOUR_AWS_KEY
    acme.aws_secret_key: YOUR_AWS_SECRET_KEY
    acme.s3.bucket_name: cool_bucket_name
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get a curl exception but that seems to be due to other problems.

Comment: In addition: You might want to add to key: ..., secret: %...%, certificate_authority: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/cacert.pem"} and then put a proper cacert.pem (search for the mozilla version of it) to your config dir.